# how can I use get_children() after I used queue_free() or free() on a node?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a main node A and a sub node of A called "B", the problem is when I 
`queue_free()` to node b and tries to see how many nodes in A it gives me the same number. I'm testing how many nodes inside A by using `get_children()` inside `_physics_process(delta)` function for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling queue_free() on a node will delete it after the current frame. Try calling get_children() after the _physics_process function restarts and you'll see that the node has been removed. Calling free() will delete it immediately but it is not recommended.